# как изменить состояние родительского класса из дочернего

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, blazor

У меня есть родительский класс Index в нём хранятcя объекты класса Card внутри класса Card есть кнопка которая может менять его состояние как мне свичить состояние родительского класса используя кнопку в дочернем
родитель:

````
<div class="card-columns" style="column-count:auto" id="main_view"</strike>

   @{\
        Requester res = new Requester();\
        for (int i = 0; i <= res.result_list.Count - 1; i++)\
        {\
            Result sampler = res.result_list[i];\
            cards.Add(new Card(sampler));
        }
    }
    @if (signal == false)
    {
        
        @foreach (var card in cards)
        {
            <ViconBaseCard card="@card" />
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    else
    {
        <ViconBigCard card="@(new Card(res.result_list[0]))" />
        StateHasChanged();
    }


</div>

@code{
    private static bool signal { get; set; }


    public List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

    //public delegate void SomeDelegate();
    //SomeDelegate sd = new SomeDelegate(EventWorker);


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        signal = false;
    }


    protected  void EventWorker()
    {
        signal = !signal;

    }


} ```
````

дитя:

```
        @code {
            [Parameter]
            public Card card { get; set; }

            public string Title { get; set; }
            public int Fill_progress_OOP { get; set; }
            private string Fill_progress_OOP_persent { get => (Fill_progress_OOP.ToString()) + "%"; }
            private string Color_progress_OOP { get => Fill_progress_OOP > 90 ? "bg-success" : Fill_progress_OOP > 50 ? "bg-warning" : "bg-danger"; }

            public int Fill_progress_YP { get; set; }
            private string Fill_progress_YP_persent { get => (Fill_progress_YP.ToString()) + "%"; }
            private string Color_progress_YP { get => Fill_progress_YP > 90 ? "bg-success" : Fill_progress_YP > 50 ? "bg-warning" : "bg-danger"; }

            private bool signal { get; set; }
            public string resize_width { get; set; }
            public string resize_heigh { get; set; }
            private string str_connect { get; set; }

            protected override void OnInitialized()
            {
                resize_width = "18rem";
                resize_heigh = "20rem";
                signal = false;
            }
            protected void EventWorker()
            {
                signal = !signal;
                
                
                StateHasChanged();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Для начала придется научится различать классы и объекты. А так, по общей концепции рвзработки, логический родитель должен следить за своими внутренностями и реагировать на изменения в них, а не наоборот. Хвост не должен вилять собакой.

Comment: Возможно вам поможет вот это https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.

Comment: для таких случаев подойдет событийная модель
но вообще aepot выше прав

Comment: Ваша задача решается с помощью организации обратного вызова, метода родительского компонента из дочернего компонента, с помощью EventCallback,  не знаю где найти бесплатное описание этого для Blazor,   на русском языке. Но платное есть на Udemy [в вводном курсе по Blazor](https://www.udemy.com/course/blazor_introduction/)